# Problem with data flow between Angular components

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a webpage structure like the following:

[image: page layout]

- Button should select/unselect all the rows of the table.
- Button and Table are separate components injected into the page.
- Table is using Material's `SelectionModel`.

From the page I'm reaching `selection.selected` of the Table through `@ViewChild` decorator. Its easy to place the selection logic in the page as it's where the table is injected, but this requires to place the same logic in every page where the button needs to be.
I'd like to simplify this by placing the logic inside the Button component so all that should be done to have the functionality is to insert its selector into page's template. But there's a catch I can't overcome:

**How to reach `selection.selected` of the Table from the Button component?**

What is the best practice to achieve this?

Here's how does it look like in the Page class

```js
    @ViewChild(TableComponent)
    private table: TableComponent;


    // ...


    checkAll(): void {
        const numSelected = this.table.selection.selected.length;
        const numRows = this.table.dataSource.data.length;
        const result = numSelected === numRows;
        result
            ? this.table.selection.clear()
            : this.table.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.table.selection.select(row));
    }
```

And here's the template html file:

```html
    <button (click)="checkAll()">Check all</button>
    <app-table></app-table>
```

Comment: Please show your current implementation. Without it people are left to guesswork.

Comment: I don't require full implementation of the solution, but just a way of thinking ;) anyways I added the code samples to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of RxJS's `Subject`, put it in service which you'll inject via constructor to both the button and table components.
Your service implementation may look like the following:

```js
// service
export class TableService {
    private event: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
    public event$ = this.event.asObservable();

    public emitEvent(event?: MouseEvent): void {
        this.event.next();
    }
}
```

Then you take this service and inject it in your button component:

```js
// button component
export class Button {

    constructor(private tableService: TableService) {}

    update(): void {
        this.tableService.emitEvent();
    }
}
```

you can activate the *update()* function on click in html template file.
Then implement the selection logic in your table and just use the `event$` to trigger it:

```js
// table component
export class Table {

    constructor(private tableService: TableService) {
        this.tableService.event$.subscribe(() => this.checkAll());
    }

    checkAll(): void {
        // your selection logic goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: thats the way i was looking for :) thank you good samaritan

Answer (score 1):

Use a service with a RxJS Subject. The service can be injected both in the button component and the table component. Through the constructor. When the button is
Clicked you trigger the service subject that the table component subscribe to. Google ‘subject service angular’

Alternative you could create a component that includes the button and the table. The button would then not need to be a component. And the button click logic would only be implemented once.

Comment: so the service is a way to go i guess

Comment: Hmm second thought. The problem is that the button component will be very specialized. If you think you will need the constellation: “a table and a button to select all rows in a table”, then THAT should be the component. But I recommend you not to create any components before you have the second use case of it